# I am unable parse date info from a csv file into ipython

Tags: date, csv, parsing, pandas, ipython

I am running python 3.5, I have imported pandas. My csv file (payinfo.csv) looks like:

```
"01 DEC",1234.45,2344,11,1212.66 

"01 NOV", 9898.33, 2343,12,1009.33
```

When I run the following:

```
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x,"%d %b")
pay_data = pd.read_csv('payinfo.csv', parse_dates = ['Date'], date_parse
```

I always get

> "ValueError: time data '“01 DEC”' does not match format '%d %b'

I am a new programmer to python, and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it was just the double quotes around string that caused that error. Try stripping away any hardcoded (not 'python generated') single or double quote marks with `.strip('"')`

**Example:**

```
a = '"01 DEC"'
# Gives error
#a = pd.datetime.strptime(a,"%d %b")

# string without unneccessary quote marks
a = pd.datetime.strptime(a.strip('"'),"%d %b")
print a
```

Output:

```
1900-12-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't included the headers in the question. But this works:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

a = io.StringIO(u""""01 DEC",1234.45,2344,11,1212.66 

"01 NOV", 9898.33, 2343,12,1009.33""")

dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x,"%d %b")
df = pd.read_csv(a,header=None, parse_dates=[0], date_parser=dateparse)
print df
```

You can append custom year to x before converting it to datetime 
`.strptime(year + x,"%Y%d %b")`
Output:

```
           0        1     2   3        4
0 1900-12-01  1234.45  2344  11  1212.66
1 1900-11-01  9898.33  2343  12  1009.33
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your input. From your answers I modified the csv file to remove the quotes around the date entry, then things worked fine! I am puzzled because I have used the read_csv method before on similar data that looked like this:
"12/31/2016","The UPS Store","THE UPS STORE 031","10.74","debit","Business Services","Interest Checking","",""

"12/31/2016","Hospice of The East Bay","HOSPICE OF THE EAST","14.00","debit","Clara","Interest Checking","",""

and had no problems – in fact I didn't need to parse the data at all and the reader was able to correctly identify the date. Huh! I guess the real issue was that the date was stored in an unconventional format. In any case, I have the answer and thank you both for your answers.